# How to use two or more ultrasonic transducer drivers?

Tags: analog, signal, ultrasound

My circuit is below, it has two ultrasonic transducers, transformers and drivers. The transformer is [B78416A2232A003](https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/inf/85/ds/B78416A2232A003.pdf), the transducer is [MCUSD14A40S09RS-30C](https://www.newark.com/multicomp/mcusd14a40s09rs-30c/transceiver-40khz-14mm-metal/dp/17X2008), the driver is [PGA460-Q1](https://www.ti.com/product/PGA460). Digital interface wires isn't shown.

<sub>**Schematic 1**</sub>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f27Qmi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Transducers is mounted opposite each other in distance 88 mm. The one can burst pulses, the other can listen. This is a waveform plot measured on B1 when B1 burst 20 pulses. Blue curve is a raw ADC samples, orange is BPF-processed waveform, green curve is an envelope.

<sub>**Figure 1**</sub>
[image: Waveform]

Waveform has "swing period"<sup>1</sup> ~54 us, pulse generation period ~486 us, decay period.

<sup>1</sup>*If you know more appropriate term you can edit my question.*

Now let's see the waveform measured on B2 when signal is burst by *separate* circuit. This circuit has it's own voltage source and doesn't have any common wires with measuring circuit. This transducer is driven by waveform generator that burst 4 pulses with time interval 700 us.

<sub>**Figure 2**</sub>
[image: Waveform from Agilent]

We can see nice waveform that can be easily detected and processed.

Now let's see the waveform measured on B2 when B1 burst signal and B2 listen.

<sub>**Figure 3**</sub>
[image: Listen waveform on B2]

Firstly, B2 started signal listening (see vertical red time mark). Then B1 started burst (see second vertical red time mark). This time moments are fine measured and plotted.

We can see mark "Burst received". Time between marks "Burst received" and "Burst started" is ~51 us, that is approximately equal to "swing period" on plot 1. We also can see two humps. The second hump looks like real wave received by transducer, and it's propagation time is ~243 us, and when speed of sound is 350 m/s, the distance is 85 mm. Nice.

But the first hump is a trouble. Why is it appeared? Since time between marks "Burst received" and "Burst started" is near to "swing period" on plot 1, and voltage levels are above the ADC measuring limits, I can suppose that the signal from *driving PGA* is propagated on wires to the *measuring PGA*. Two circuits has common HVGND wire. I've made modification of the circuit decoupling this wire. The new version is below.

<sub>**Schematic 2**</sub>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHOR5y.png)</sup>

Now, when B1 burst and B2 listen, the waveform looks so strange:

<sub>**Figure 4**</sub>
[image]

The signal has pulse frequency 104 kHz. When I measure signal on transducer with oscilloscope I can see sine wave with same frequency. So, this modification is wrong.

So, is my hypothesis about signal propagation on wires right? How can I modify this circuit to make signal wouldn't be able to propagate from one transducer to another?

---

### Update 24 May 2023

Recent modifications:

1. C8, C15 is replaced with 100 uF.
2. Each PGA460 has its own HVGND connected with common GND via ferrite bead L1 MI1206K601R-10 as datasheet says (Figure 8-1).

The new circuit:

<sub>**Schematic 3**</sub>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faaZDt.png)</sup>

The result is below:

<sub>**Figure 5**</sub>
[image: Ferrite beads]

Nothing is changed.

Comment: Why R2 and R5 are in these schematics and not in figures 7-37 and 7-38 of the data sheet?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the purpose of having ultrasonic transducers facing each other with 88mm spacing? 

How is the data in the plot measured? Is it data extracted from the PGA460s or measured with a oscilloscope or external ADC?

Comment: @Antonio51, this resistors are in figure 8-1. I suppose figures 7-37, 7-38 just describes time and temperature decoupling and don't have information about measuring. Figure 8-1 has full circuit.

Comment: @PeterKarlsen, the purpose is wind measurement. The data are extracted from PGA460s in *Direct Data Burst mode* (Datasheet, section 7.3.7.2).

Comment: @maestro Yes, ok. I did not see this figure.

Comment: @maestro, I've worked quite a bit with PGA460. My experience is, that it it takes a LOT of tweaking of the parameters of the transmitter and receiver. Too strong a transmit signal, and you will get a lot of echos from the soundwaves bouncing all over the place. The gain settings of the receiver is also very important to get good detection.

Comment: >>> How can I modify this circuit to make signal wouldn't be able to propagate from one transducer to another? <<< ... Perhaps using inductors between 10GND and HVGND1 ... and HNGND2 in place of R4?

Comment: @PeterKarlsen, the first hump doesn't look like echo. It appears exactly when another transducer starts bursting. When raw ADC samples are extracted from PGA460 via Direct Data Burst mode, any gains are disabled.

Comment: @Antonio51, Datasheet says to use ferrite bead between 10DGND and HVGND. *Optional, noise reduction. Can be substituted with 0-Ohm short*. I've placed 0-Ohm short. What do you think, it would be better to use *inductor* or *ferrite bead*? What magnitude of inductor? And HVGND wires between transducers still will be connected after this modification, will this modification really help to remove first hump?

Comment: @maestro Ferrite bead should be the "best". Removing the first hump, don't know ...

Comment: @maestro, could it be electrical/magnetic coupling between the two transformers? Do you need to transmit with both curcuits? If not I would try removing the transformer from the receiving circuit.

Comment: @PeterKarlsen, transmit with both circuits is desirable but not necessarily. I will test your solution.

Comment: Are transducers mounted (88mm apart) on a rigid structure? Could this structure provide acoustic coupling path? Perhaps your successful function-generator test was done with different mounting.

Comment: @glen_geek, I already tested this idea. The device has brass skeleton, and transducers is mounted onto it with organosilicon sealant. If the acoustic wave were propagated via skeleton, it would be detected in ~34 us. Really we can see received wave in 0<sup>+3</sup><sub>-0</sub> us. I tried to make the same test when the transducer was unmounted and had been hanging on wires. The results were the same as plotted in figure 3.

Comment: @PeterKarlsen, I tried removing transformer XFMR2 and C10, and replaced C8 with 100 uF (as datasheet says). There are no changes. Now I will test ferrite bead.